# Petite heure, bonne heure

Tags: expressions, locutions, comparatifs, langage-informel

D'après mon expérience, on utilise fréquemment (en France métropolitaine) les expressions *une petite heure*, *une bonne heure* dans le sens *un peu moins qu'une heure*, *un peu plus que une heure*. Ça marche aussi avec d'autres unités du temps: *une petite demi-heure*, *un petit quart d'heure*, *une bonne vingtaine de minutes*.

Q1: Peut-on utiliser ces expressions dans un contexte autre que le contexte temporel ? Par exemple : *un bon kilomètre*, *un petit kilo de pommes* ?

Q2: S'agit-il d'une utilisation informelle/familière ou peut-on utiliser ces expressions à l'écrit ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Les adjectifs *bon* et *petit* sont très souvent utilisés pour exprimer une certaine intensité ou une certaine quantité.

Quand je fais mon marché je dis souvent :

- Je voudrais un petit kilo d'oranges.

Comme on ne va pas couper une orange en deux, ça veut dire que je demande de peser plutôt en dessous du kilo. Et si je voulais que ce soit pesé au-dessus je demanderais de m'en mettre un « bon kilo ».

Quelques exemples :

- La gare est à un bon/petit kilomètre d'ici.
- Je suis crevé, on a dû faire une bonne dizaine de kilomètres.
- À la dernière panne d'électricité une bonne partie de la ville s'est retrouvée dans le noir.
- Il est encore jeune, il a tout au plus une/la petite quarantaine.
- Nous étions nombreux, probablement une bonne cinquantaine.
- La température a baissé d'un bon/petit degré.

J'utilise parfois *gros* dans ce sens à la place de *bon* : un gros kilo, une grosse cinquantaine.

L'utilisation de *bon* et *petit* pour exprimer une certaine quantité est du langage familier, que ce soit à l'écrit comme à l'oral. Et utiliser *gros* au lieu de *bon* est à mon avis encore plus familier.

Une autre « unité de mesure » qu'on emploie souvent avec *bon* c'est la *rasade*. Au sens propre une rasade est une quantité de boisson qui correspond à un verre rempli à ras bord, alors quand je demande qu'on me verse une « bonne rasade » de whisky, pris à la lettre c'est plutôt drôle.

Comment: La question a été posée une bonne petite heure avant que tu y répondes... ;-)

Comment: *Longtemps, je me suis couché de bonne heure...*